# Have AWS Athena assume role for accessing external S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I set up an Athena table via Glue in my account that is supposed to query the data in my friends account. My friend created an IAM role I can assume that has permission to access the S3 data.

My Athena queries error out complaining that they don't have permission to access the S3 bucket. Is there a way to make Athena assume the role so it can get to the S3 bucket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming roles through Athena is currently not possible. AWS does suggest using bucket policies for accessing s3 buckets across accounts.

The only currently possible setup is described over [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/access.html) in the "Cross-account Permissions" section.

Answer (score -1):

Cross Account enablement is not required.

#### Hosting Account  (Account A)

1. Have the Athena Policy/ Resource Level Policy
2. Create a Role (to be assumed by another account B) and attach the Policy created in step 1
3. Update the Trusted Entities: Include the IAM User/ Role in another account B

   ```
    {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": [
              "arn:aws:iam::Account B:user/User A"
            ]
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
          "Condition": {}
        }
      ]
    }
   ```

#### Consuming Application

1. Create a Policy

   ```
   {
       "Version": "2012-10-17",
       "Statement": [
           {
               "Effect": "Allow",
               "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
               "Resource": [
                   "arn:aws:iam::Account A:role/Role Created in Step 2 as Hosting Account A"
               ]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
2. Attach the Policy to the User